# How do I install numpy/core/numeric.py file on my machine; I want isclose()

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, numpy

I'm missing something basic.

There seems to be some added functionality, specifically isclose(), on GitHub **[here](https://github.com/joferkington/numpy/blob/3a85c0a9af64b0296b9a4c97f43f2f209c849077/numpy/core/numeric.py)** that isn't available through my install.

I did the following:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/numpy/numpy.git numpy
```

But it didn't seem to work.

I also checked for an update through the *Synaptic Package Manager*, but that didn't do the trick either.  What am I missing?  How may I obtain the "latest' version?

I'm running python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you linked to is Joe Kington's fork of the numpy package.

The `git clone` command you posted downloads the source code for that fork to your local machine. You would then have to compile numpy and install it before you could use this version of numpy.

The easiest way to obtain the `isclose` function is to simply copy the code into a file and import it:

**utils_num.py**

```
import numpy as np
def isclose(a, b, rtol=1.e-5, atol=1.e-8, equal_nan=False):
    """
    https://github.com/joferkington/numpy/blob/3a85c0a9af64b0296b9a4c97f43f2f209c849077/numpy/core/numeric.py
    Returns a boolean array where two arrays are element-wise equal within a
    tolerance.

    The tolerance values are positive, typically very small numbers.  The
    relative difference (`rtol` * abs(`b`)) and the absolute difference
    `atol` are added together to compare against the absolute difference
    between `a` and `b`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a, b : array_like
        Input arrays to compare.
    rtol : float
        The relative tolerance parameter (see Notes).
    atol : float
        The absolute tolerance parameter (see Notes).
    equal_nan : bool
        Whether to compare NaN's as equal.  If True, NaN's in `a` will be
        considered equal to NaN's in `b` in the output array.

    Returns
    -------
    y : array_like
        Returns a boolean array of where `a` and `b` are equal within the
        given tolerance. If both `a` and `b` are scalars, returns a single
        boolean value.

    See Also
    --------
    allclose

    Notes
    -----
    For finite values, isclose uses the following equation to test whether
    two floating point values are equivalent.
     absolute(`a` - `b`) <= (`atol` + `rtol` * absolute(`b`))
    The above equation is not symmetric in `a` and `b`, so that
    `isclose(a, b)` might be different from `isclose(b, a)` in
    some rare cases.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> np.isclose([1e10,1e-7], [1.00001e10,1e-8])
    array([True, False])
    >>> np.isclose([1e10,1e-8], [1.00001e10,1e-9])
    array([True, True])
    >>> np.isclose([1e10,1e-8], [1.0001e10,1e-9])
    array([False, True])
    >>> np.isclose([1.0, np.nan], [1.0, np.nan])
    array([True, False])
    >>> np.isclose([1.0, np.nan], [1.0, np.nan], equal_nan=True)
    array([True, True])
    """
    def within_tol(x, y, atol, rtol):
        result = np.less_equal(abs(x - y), atol + rtol * abs(y))
        if np.isscalar(a) and np.isscalar(b):
            result = result[0]
        return result
    x = np.array(a, copy=False, ndmin=1)
    y = np.array(b, copy=False, ndmin=1)
    xfin = np.isfinite(x)
    yfin = np.isfinite(y)
    if np.all(xfin) and np.all(yfin):
        return within_tol(x, y, atol, rtol)
    else:
        # Avoid subtraction with infinite/nan values...
        cond = np.zeros(broadcast(x, y).shape, dtype=bool)
        mask = xfin & yfin
        cond[mask] = within_tol(x[mask], y[mask], atol, rtol)
        # Check for equality of infinite values...
        cond[~mask] = (x[~mask] == y[~mask])
        if equal_nan:
            # Make NaN == NaN
            cond[isnan(x) & isnan(y)] = True
        return cond
```

**test.py:**

```
import utils_num as UN
print(UN.isclose([1e10,1e-7], [1.00001e10,1e-8]))
```

yields

```
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

To install that version of numpy you need to `cd` into the `numpy/` directory/repo that you just cloned

and run

```
python setup.py install
```

that should do the trick